# "The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'.";

Tags: ios, json, swift, post

I am trying to make a **POST** request using `Alamofire` in my application but continuously getting below result-:

```
SUCCESS: {
    "$id" = 1;
    Message = "The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'.";
}
```

I have tested my parameters in `POSTMAN` and i am getting correct result there, but facing issue in application.

[image]

Code in networking class -:

```
 // Mark-: User Login

    static func saveUserLoginDetails(url: String, parameters: [String: String]) {
        print(parameters)
        Alamofire.request(url,method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: ["Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]).responseJSON {
            response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                print(response)

                break
            case .failure(let error):

                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Method in Login class calling login `API` upon `button` click-:

```
 private func saveUserLoginResponse(){
    AbcNetworking.saveUserLoginDetails(url:Constant.URL.school_Code , parameters: [
         "grant_type":"password",
         "username" : "surabhi@gmail.com",
         "password":"lakhera8",
         "Scope":"User"])
    }
```

Comment: I’d double check the URL. Sometimes you can hit the wrong URL, resulting in one that doesn’t accept `POST`. Other issues might include omitting some header included in the postman request. But you might want to watch the request in [Charles](https://charlesproxy.com) or [Wireshark](https://wireshark.org) and compare to your postman request.

Comment: By the way, why are you setting the `Content-Type` header? Alamofire does that for you, and manually setting this is just an invitation for mistakes.

Comment: Hi Rob, I was just testing it with every possible ways. Well I will check the URL, and get back on this.

Comment: Yeah, Charles/Wireshark show you the raw request, eliminating any guesswork as to what was actually sent to the web service. It decouples the “what request did my code generate?” from the “is the request what the server expected?”.